# Updating JSONField default in Django value for all records

Tags: python, django, postgresql

While using JSONField with Django and Postgres, Im setting a default value as such

```
{
    "custom_value_a": "foo",
    "custom_value_b": "bar"
}
```

Consider that after a period of time I want to change the default value of the field by adding another key into it

```
"custom_value_c": "oof"
```

One way of doing this would be to run a script which iterates through all the records and updates the JSONField to include the key:value in all of the records in the DB.

Is there any other method to update the it via the Django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(TheModel)
class TheModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['custom_action']
    def custom_action(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(json_fld__custom_value_c='oof')
```

Comment: what do you mean? it's self explanatory